# Displaying progress of time consuming SQL Server stored procedure (or query) in wpf UI

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, mvvm

I am developing a Windows application using WPF and this application uses MVVM. In this application I need to deal with time consuming SQL Server queries or stored procedures. Now I want to display progress of running query/stored procedure in UI. I am using SQL Server as database.

How can I achieve that? please help.

Regards,
Anirban

Comment: Unless you specifically provide some means of communicating back the "progress" of your stored procedure, I don't think there's any way to do this. With a normal SQL query or stored procedure, you launch it and some time later you get the results - there's no built-in mechanism to provide "progress" reports.

Comment: You could just show an indeterminate progress indicator - a spinning wheel etc usually will let the user know something is processing (if you also include a message to say that the process may take a while then they know the application hasn't crashed)

Answer (score 2):

It is irrespective of technology , fist you have to figure out how you will get the stage of the query. You can have one table with Id as some uniqueGUID , which you will return to the to the calling code. Now in your SP you can pass the GUID and with every step completed you can update the counter in the database table with the GUID. Now you just need one independent thread pinging the table every 1-2 seconds and fetch  the status reached so far using the GUID you have got while starting of the process.

Comment: Never thought of something like this. Great idea!

Comment: I was looking for some kind of sql mechanism that tells me what is the status of the progress.But if there is no such mechanism, then I have to follow your suggestion.